# Linq getting a list from another list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have two collections: one is Items And Another is ActiveItems

The only intersection between these two collection is Name

I want a list with Linq from Items where the Items names are in the ActiveItems with that name

I wrote this code is there a better idea:

```
Items.Where(i => ActiveItems.Count(v=> v.Name==i.Name) > 0)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would probably create a set of the names from `ActiveItems` and then use that:

```
var activeNames = new HashSet<string>(activeItems.Select(x => x.Name));
var itemsWithActiveNames = items.Where(x => activeNames.Contains(x.Name))
                                .ToList();
```

Another option is to use a join, e.g. with a query expression:

```
var query = from activeItem in activeItems
            join item in items on activeItem.Name equals item.Name
            select item;
```

Note that this will give duplicate `item` values if there are multiple `ActiveItem` values with the same name. Another alternative join, which doesn't have this problem but is a bit clumsier:

```
var query = from item in items
            join activeItem in activeItems 
                on item.Name equals activeItem.Name
                into g
            where g.Any()
            select item;
```

Note that all of these will avoid the O(N * M) check for names - they'll all use hash tables behind the scenes, to give an O(N + M) complexity.

Comment: No I don't want properties from another collection

Comment: will solutions 2 and 3 use HashSets internally without `activeNames` being one?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes... I just find the first version is clearer when you don't really need the joins :)

Answer (score 7):

```
Items.where(i => ActiveItems.Any(a => i.Name == a.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from i1 in collection1.Items
              join i2 in collection2.ActiveItems on i1.Name equals i2.Name
              select i2.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a join:

```
from item in Items
join active in ActiveItems on item.Name equals active.Name
select item
```

Comment: the join should be ... on item.Name equals active.Name. Sequence is important